# Dependency propery for ValueConverter or rebind control?

Tags: wpf, text, binding, case, ivalueconverter

I have custom control with some text in content template:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:TouchScreenKey}">    
    <TextBlock><ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Title, Converter={StaticResource CaseConverter}}" /></TextBlock>
</ControlTemplate>
```

and custom IValueConverter CaseConverter - with property UpperCase. So, when UpperCase property of converter set to true it converts text to upper case on binding. Everything goes fine if I change UpperCase in markup. But if i change property in runtime - nothing happens - because changing converter property not force my control to rebind. 
How can I rebind control which uses converter on converter's property change?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no way to tell converter to update all targets. Converter knows nothing about targets. It's just a stateless function, `F(x)`, takes one value and returns another.

To update property you should ask WPF to do so. For example, if property is bound to some source property, you can implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx), and trigger `PropertyChanged` event. Or you can ask `BindingOperations` to [get binding expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingoperations.getbindingexpression.aspx), and invoke [UpdateTarget()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingexpression.updatetarget.aspx) manually.

Maybe converter isn't the best choice here? You may also want to consider using [Attached Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx) to change capitalization.

Comment: Thanks for answer, i solved that with Multibinding and MultiValueConverter

Comment: You are welcome :). I'm glad you could find the answer yourself. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

It may help someone - I found solution - using multibinding

```
<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
<ContentPresenter>
    <ContentPresenter.Content>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiCaseConverter}">
            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" Path="Title" />
            <Binding ElementName="TouchKeyboard" Path="UpperCase" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </ContentPresenter.Content>
</ContentPresenter>
```

and wrote MultiCaseConverter - which convert first parameter depending from second (UpperCase)